# Quartz Setup (ASP.Net Server- A, Quartz Service - Server B and SQL Server -Server C

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, quartz-scheduler

we are looking into several Job scheduling solutions for a small enterprize level applications. Compared hangfire vs quartz 
as of now quartz seems like a solution for us as there are several asp.net applications that schedules jobs by sending job 
schedule request to a dedicated quartz service (Server B), Server B keep listening to the Job requests and as job comes 
it has to queue the job and trigger as per setting or even run on demand or trigger immediately etc.

My questions are, is this kind of set up is possible ? 
if possible how can a App server (Server A) send the job request to Server B ?
Where is the job logic is stored (on Server A (application) or Server B (Q-Scheduler) ? 
Is it possible to pass the DLL (code assembly that have serialized job logic ) to Server B , where Server B can deserialize the DLL by reading from Database ?

I am really confused by reading so many topics on Quartz set up as a service vs embedded but your set up is kind of similar on what I am looking for. 
Could you please give me some pointers. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Quartz store namespace and method name in DB (if you set up AdoJobStore), therefore it knows which dll from its bin folder will execute job. 
So the answer on your question is, App Server (Server A) can schedule jobs which will be executed on Server B(quartz server).

Comment: Thanks for the response Stanislav, so the DLL's needed to be dropped in the Serer B's bin ? Trying to understand the process, as we create new jobs we enter an entry in AdoJobStore for that job and drop the DLL as a plug-in ?

Comment: DLL which will execute job needs to be in bin folder.  Little documentation about job stores in quartz: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html